# $X$ is compactly generated (not necessarily Hausdorff) and $Y$ is locally compact, then is $X\times Y$ still compactly generated?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, product-space

While looking at a proposition from Hatcher AT:

Proposition A.15. If $X$ is a compactly generated Hausdorff space and $Y$ is locally
compact, then the product topology on X×Y is compactly generated.

Is it necessary for $X$ to be Hausdorff in order for $X \times Y$ to be compactly generated?

Below I give an argument why the condition is not needed, but this theory is new to me, and I am extremely unsure about it's validity.

Hatcher uses the condition of Hausdorffness of $X$, in the fact that a compact Hausdorff space is locally compact, which I think it can be avoided by my below argument:

Argument: We want to prove $f:X\times Y \rightarrow (X\times Y)_c$ is continuous. Since $Y$ is locally compact is enough to prove that for any $K\subset X$, compact, the function $f:K\times Y \rightarrow (X\times Y)_c$ is continuous.

So fix such a $K\subset X$ compact. We know that $f:K\times C \rightarrow (X\times Y)_c$ is continous for any compact $C\subset Y$. For each $y\in Y$, we pick a compact neighborhood $C_y$. Since $f$ is continuous on $K \times C_y$, it must be that $f$ is continuous on $K\times int(C_y)$, which is an open subset of $K\times C$. Therefore $f$ is continous on \begin{equation} \bigcup_{y\in Y} K\times int(C_y)=K \times Y, \end{equation}

the idea is that $f$ is continuous on a cover of open sets of $K \times Y$, therefore is continuous on $K \times Y$.

Comment: What is the definition of compactly generated you're working with?

Comment: It's true that compact Hausdorff spaces must be locally compact; in fact, any regular weakly locally compact space must be locally compact: https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000246 But there are compactly generated spaces that are not locally compact: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Generated%20by%20compact%20Hausdorff%20subspaces%2B~Locally%20Compact The same goes for weakly locally compact spaces without T2: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Weakly%20Locally%20Compact%2B~Locally%20Compact

Comment: @StevenClontz, the definition for compactly generated I am using is : $X$ is compactly generated if it coincides with the topology generated by all the compact sets from $X$. Meaning $C \subset X$ is closed if $C\cap K$ is closed in $K$ for any $K\subset X$ compact subset. So there is no Hausdorffness condition impossed, unlike in the $k$-spaces which are by definition compactly generated plus Hausdorff.

Comment: @StevenClontz, yes compact Hausdorff spaces must be locally compact. When I said "can be avoided by me argument" I meant that we can avoid the condition for $X$ to be Hausdorff, and proposition A.15, still be true.

Comment: Understood. Then what is $(X\times Y)_c$ and how does it relate to the definition you're using?

Comment: The topology on $(X\times Y)_c$ is the one generated by the compact subsets of $X\times Y$, this last space has the product topology. We observe that in this context the topology $(X\times Y)_c$ can be finer/larger than the product one on $X \times Y$. Moreover these topologies have the same compact subsets and have the same induced topology on them.

It relates by the fact that in order to prove $X \times Y$ is compactly generated we only need to prove that the product topology coincides with the topology on $(X\times Y)_c$.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. And I guess $f$ is the identity function as well then: given that $(X\times Y)_c$ is finer, the identity function is an open bijection; showing it's continuous would give a homeomorphism.